# TensorFlow code not giving intended results

Tags: tensorflow

The following code has the irritating trait of making every row of "out" the same. I am trying to classify k time series in Xtrain as [1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], or [0,0,0,1], according to the way they were generated (by one of four random algorithms). Anyone know why?  Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

n = 100
m = 10
k = 1000
hidden_layers = 50
learning_rate = .01
training_epochs = 10000

Xtrain = []
Xtest = []
Ytrain = []
Ytest = []

# ... fill variables with data ..

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape = (k,1,n,1))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape = (k,1,4))

conv1_weights = 0.1*tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1,m,1,hidden_layers],dtype = tf.float64))
conv1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_layers],tf.float64))

conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x,conv1_weights,strides = [1,1,1,1],padding = 'VALID')
sigmoid1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(conv + conv1_biases)

s = sigmoid1.get_shape()
sigmoid1_reshape = tf.reshape(sigmoid1,(s[0],s[1]*s[2]*s[3]))

sigmoid2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.layers.dense(sigmoid1_reshape,hidden_layers))
sigmoid3 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.layers.dense(sigmoid2,4))

penalty = tf.reduce_sum((sigmoid3 - y)**2)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(penalty)

model = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(model)
    for i in range(0,training_epochs):
        sess.run(train_op,{x: Xtrain,y: Ytrain})

    out = sigmoid3.eval(feed_dict = {x: Xtest})
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely because your loss function is mean squared error. If you're doing classification you should be using cross-entropy loss

Comment: Nope, was not a fix.  Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your loss is `penalty = tf.reduce_sum((sigmoid3 - y)**2)` that's the squared difference elementwise between a **batch** of predictions and a batch of values.

Your network output (`sigmoid3`) is a tensor with shape `[?, 4]` and `y` (I guess) is a tensor with shape `[?, 4]` too.

The squared difference has thus shape `[?, 4]`.

This means that the `tf.reduce_sum` is computing in order:

1. The sum over the second dimension of the squared difference, producing a tensor with shape `[?]`
2. The sum over the first dimension (the batch size, here indicated with `?`) producing a scalar value (shape `()`) that's your loss value.

Probably you don't want this behavior (the sum over the batch dimension) and you're looking for the mean squared error over the batch:

```
penalty = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(sigmoid3, y))
```